# Can we group by multiple columns in the same function with R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Using this dataset:

```
sex <- c("M","F","M","M","F","F","F","M","M","F") 
school <- c("north","north","central","south","south","south","central","north","north","south")
school_type <- c("high","high","primary","secondary","secondary","secondary","primary","high", "high","secondary")
days_missed <- c(5,1,2,0,7,1,3,2,4,15)

df <- data.frame(sex, school, school_type,days_missed, stringsAsFactors = F)

col1 <- c( 'school_type')
col2 <- c('school','sex')
```

Can we split the data frame by `col1` and then group each resulting data frame by `col2` to create an output like:

```
$high .x
school      sex     sum
north       F       1
north       M       11

$primary .x
school      sex     sum
central     F       3
central     M       2

$seconday .x
school      sex     sum
south       F       23
south       M        0
```

i tried:

```
purrr::map(.x=col1, .f = ~df %>% group_by_at(.x) %>%group_by(col2) %>% summarise(sum = sum(days_missed)))
```

Input and suggestions are appreicated

Comment: Is it important that the result is a list of 3 data frames or can it be just one data frame like this `df %>% group_by(school_type, school, sex) %>% summarise(days_missed = sum(days_missed))`?

Comment: Yes, it is important that each of the 3 data frames remain separate

Answer (score 2):

in base R you could do:

```
xtabs(reformulate(c(col2,col1),"days_missed"),df)
```

if your R version is >4.0.0 then you could include the `asplit` function to have it as a list:

```
asplit(xtabs(reformulate(c(col2,col1),"days_missed"),df),3)

$high
         sex
school    F  M
  central 0  0
  north   1 11
  south   0  0

$primary
         sex
school    F M
  central 3 2
  north   0 0
  south   0 0

$secondary
         sex
school     F M
  central  0 0
  north    0 0
  south   23 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sex <- c("M","F","M","M","F","F","F","M","M","F") 
school <- c("north","north","central","south","south","south","central","north","north","south")
school_type <- c("high","high","primary","secondary","secondary","secondary","primary","high", "high","secondary")
days_missed <- c(5,1,2,0,7,1,3,2,4,15)

df <- data.frame(sex, school, school_type,days_missed, stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(school_type, school, sex) %>% summarise(days_missed = sum(days_missed)) %>% ungroup()

split(select(df2, -school_type), df2$school_type)
```

Comment: Can also use `group_split` e.g. `df %>% 
  group_by(school_type, school, sex) %>% 
  summarise(days_missed = sum(days_missed)) %>% 
  group_by(school_type) %>% 
  group_split`